# Finding Main Camera in CustomUnityEditor Class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Iam writing a custom editor script in unity. I want to find the **MainCamera** in the scene for **Custom Editor class** so it can be directly assigned to the script and I dont have to assign it. I know i can find all cameras in scene and iterate over it through tags but I want to know if weather a direct method like `Camera.main` is available which brings the MainCamera of the scene in Custom Editor.

PS: I know it is easy to assign directly but still I want to do it by fetching through in custom editor script. Also I dont want to do it at runtime in start as I have some canvas related calculations which needs to be taken care of

Comment: The reason i want to use this is Camera.main is giving null in Custom Editor Class. Also because Camera.main is giving null I want to know at what time the "MainCamera" tagged object is assigned to Camera.main? I always assumed the Camera.main is always assigned in scene before today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I know this is embarrassing but here is the answer which was really simple.
You can directly use the code below to get the main camera.

`GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Camera>();`

***Note:***

This will find the first camera with tag like so if your scene has only one main camera then it will get you that and don't have to worry about `Camera.main`. But my second part of question still remains. When is the `Camera.main` is assigned?

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer to close the post ;)

Comment: I was waiting for another answer if possible about when is the Camera.main is assigned, but i guess that should be posted as another question. Thanks anyway Goblin :) LOL cannot accept till two more days as my own answer.

Comment: Be warned!  As a best practice it is almost always better to assign the camera/objects via editor and not fetching them in the code.  I know it can't always be avoided, but the GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(string).GetComponent<>() Method is one of the most expensive Unity functions.

Comment: Yes it is after Gameobject.find() but i was using this method in custom editor class and not the game itself as i have already mentioned in post i dont require it in game but to assign it on inspector. I want it to autoassign after some values are changes in inspector.